# Incremental import of Oracle tables which does not have primary key to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have Oracle database with almost 300 tables out of that 200 tables doesn't have any primary key and few tables have composite primary key. My requirement is to import all tables data in incremental manner to HDFS. Can you please let me know how this can be achieved using Sqoop. It would be great help if any other option is suggested.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried, and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: For the tables Which have single primary key I am able to import the data using Sqoop import with incremental option. I am stuck while doing incremental import for the tables Which does not have any primary key and also they don't have any timestamp column.

Comment: Is there any way for you to recognize 'new' rows? And have you tried using this knowledge?

Comment: Only number of rows gets changed and the new rows gets appended at the end. As per my understanding there is no way to identify new rows

Comment: We can use Oracle ROWNUM function to identify newly inserted rows but not updated row's.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, being unable to recognize updated rows (you indicate that you do not track update timestamps), makes it practically impossible to use incremental loads to capture the changes.

Some possibilities:

1. Add timestamps
2. Do a full load
3. Use the rownumber to identify new records, and don't process updated records